# How to update json file used for storing data for react blog app

Tags: json, reactjs, react-redux

I am working a react blog app that list article and comment towards the article. I am using a JSON file to store data in the local.
I have added button to add new comment. I having trouble with adding the new comment to JSON data.

I have imported the data to my component file. I am stuck on how to update the JSON.

```
[{
  "id": "5d403e5fbe39eb87471b8cd9",
  "title": "laboris duis veniam",
  "content": "Sint quis nisi tempor officia. occaecat pariatur sunt.\r\n",
  "author":
  {
    "_id": "5d403e5f552ff12f1d0773d0",
    "name": "Amanda Mckinney"
  },
  "comments": [
  {
    "id": "5d403e5f416a8a6b0447a069",
    "content": "Do minim Culpa nostrud laborum consectet\r\n",
    "commenter":
    {
      "_id": "5d403e5f58174caa22041e78",
      "name": "Angelina Wong"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "5d403e5f17475a36a4745241",
    "content": "Velit reprehenderit et consectetur id in .\r\n",
    "commenter":
    {
      "_id": "5d403e5f3511fa317d0bf561",
      "name": "Gail Moss"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "5d403e5f8419bad3767550b1",
    "content": "Labore veniam dolor  deserunt qui minim.\r\n",
    "commenter":
    {
      "_id": "5d403e5f28bd1b5fc4d1be1b",
      "name": "Staci Pierce"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "5d403e5f43a52dd53b63f6c6",
    "content": "Pariatur quis proident  dolor veniam laborum.\r\n",
    "commenter":
    {
      "_id": "5d403e5f33be38b996c4a8f1",
      "name": "Mai Delaney"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "5d403e5f9c53f6000ca12607",
    "content": "Labore reprehenderit pariatur culpa non\r\n",
    "commenter":
    {
      "_id": "5d403e5f1f77294e7fc77552",
      "name": "Geraldine Gilliam"
    }
  }]
}]
```

In the comment session i want to add new comment object with details such as

```
{
  "id": "5d403e5f9c53f6000ca12607",
  "content": "Labore reprehenderit pariatur culpa non\r\n",
  "commenter": {
    "_id": "5d403e5f1f77294e7fc77552",
    "name": "Geraldine Gilliam"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not write to a file of the machine in browser environment. You will have to use `Node.js` to achieve this.

Comment: Hi, I am using Node.js here as well, sorry to miss that in the question